# Userlocation keeps updating and won´t let me move freely through my map

Tags: swift, geolocation, userlocation

Let me explain myself. I have created a Map where I show some locations (pins) and the user location. When I run the App, it opens and zooms in (span), then I want to move through the map, but the App "drags" the view back to the user location (it even zooms in back to normal state). My question is, how can I stop my App from doing that over and over again? because it is kind of annoying. Thanks in advance.

The function I used for this Span process was the following...

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.0, 1.0)
    let ubicacionUsuario: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(ubicacionUsuario, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your didUpdateLocations function, you can create a counter. Essentially, what the counter would do is update and refresh the user's location on the map for a specific number of iterations. After that, you can use the `.stopUpdatingLocation` method of the `CLLocationManager`. So, for your case, you would have something like below:

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    //        Top level class stuff, create CLLocationManager Instance

    var manager = CLLocationManager()

    //        set initial value of counter to 0

    var updateCount = 0

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        //If the location has updated less than 3 times, continue to update the location

        if updateCount < 3 {
            let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(ubicacionUsuario, span)

            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

            updateCount += 1

        } else {

            //                Once the update has occurred a satisfactory number of times, prevent the update from automaitcally occuring again

            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }


    }
}
```